# Using telegram API with PHP

Tags: php, curl, telegram

I'm trying to use the Telegram API to make an online advertising app with PHP, but the problem I have is that I can't even understand making request to telegram website. This is a short code I wrote based on Telegram's API and protocol:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Length" content="348">
    <meta http-equiv="Connection" content="keep-alive">
    <meta http-equiv="Host" content="149.154.167.40:80">
</head>

<body>
<?php
$url = '149.154.167.40';

$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($curl);

echo $result;

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone have any idea how to make it work?

Comment: -.-- --- ..- / ... .... --- ..- .-.. -.. / .- ... -.- / - .... . / ...- . -. -.. --- .-. .-.-.- You should ask the vendor, do they have support forums?  Otherwise are you getting any errors?  Be more specific.  Do you just need to [tell cURL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) to return transfer maybe?

Comment: no forum, and it just returns "501 Not Implemented" on "nginx/0.3.33", as I understood based on the protocol they use we should make a keep-alive connection and post to the url they gave to us.

Comment: Ahh, maybe the you need to tell cURL to follow redirects?  `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION `  Also, if it is routed as HTTPS might need to tell cURL To ignore certificate validation.  No other authentication required when making request?

Comment: I changed curl_setopt() to curl_setopt_array($curl, array(   CURLOPT_URL => $url,
CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => FALSE
));
Still not working.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3757071/php-debugging-curl

Comment: I checked it thats the reslt:

Verbose information:
* Rebuilt URL to: 149.154.167.40/
* Hostname was found in DNS cache
* Hostname in DNS cache was stale, zapped
*   Trying 149.154.167.40...
* Connected to 149.154.167.40 (149.154.167.40) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: 149.154.167.40
Accept: */*

< HTTP/1.1 501 Not Implemented
< Server: nginx/0.3.33
< Date: Thu, 02 Jul 2015 18:19:07 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 181
< Connection: close
< 
* Closing connection

Comment: have you ever solved this?

Comment: @T.Todua GitHub repo if it can help: https://github.com/amirmasoud/telegram-bot-manager

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Telegram API is a pain to use, you have to apply all sort of encryption sorcery to work with their MTProto protocol and there's very little reference or example for PHP available. I would suggest you use their new [Bot API](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api). It is a service the created that abstracts all the MTProto interactions behind a simple HTTP layer. You first need to generate a bot using their [Bot Father](https://core.telegram.org/bots#botfather) and then you use the ID to interact with the API.

**Receiving new messages (polling):**

```
<?php

$bot_id = "<bot ID generated by BotFather>";

# Note: you want to change the offset based on the last update_id you received
$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $bot_id . '/getUpdates?offset=0';
$result = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($result, true);

foreach ($result['result'] as $message) {
    var_dump($message);
}
```

**Sending messages:**

```
# The chat_id variable will be provided in the getUpdates result
$url = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot' . $bot_id . '/sendMessage?text=message&chat_id=0';
$result = file_get_contents($url);
$result = json_decode($result, true);

var_dump($result['result']);
```

You can also use a webhook instead of polling for updates. You can find more information in the API documentation I linked.

Comment: This API doesn't have the method I want, one which obtains message info by channel/id, so I need an answer to the author's original question. :/

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library:

PHP implementation of the telegram MTProto protocol (better tg-cli)
https://github.com/danog/MadelineProto

Simple sample code:

```
<?php

if (!file_exists('madeline.php')) {
    copy('https://phar.madelineproto.xyz/madeline.php', 'madeline.php');
}
include 'madeline.php';

$MadelineProto = new \danog\MadelineProto\API('session.madeline');
$MadelineProto->start();

$me = $MadelineProto->get_self();

\danog\MadelineProto\Logger::log($me);

if (!$me['bot']) {
    $MadelineProto->messages->sendMessage(['peer' => '@danogentili', 'message' => "Hi!\nThanks for creating MadelineProto! <3"]);
    $MadelineProto->channels->joinChannel(['channel' => '@MadelineProto']);

    try {
        $MadelineProto->messages->importChatInvite(['hash' => 'https://t.me/joinchat/Bgrajz6K-aJKu0IpGsLpBg']);
    } catch (\danog\MadelineProto\RPCErrorException $e) {
    }

    $MadelineProto->messages->sendMessage(['peer' => 'https://t.me/joinchat/Bgrajz6K-aJKu0IpGsLpBg', 'message' => 'Testing MadelineProto!']);
}
echo 'OK, done!'.PHP_EOL;
```